# Flutter failed to create a directory

Tags: android, android-studio, flutter

It says that

> ```
> Flutter failed to create a directory at "C:\Program Files\first_app". The flutter tool cannot access the file.
> Please ensure that the SDK and/or project is installed in a location that has read/write permissions for the current
> user.
> ```

**first_app** is the file that I wanted to create in flutter file.

Comment: you dont have the permission to write in the Program File ( becuase is a systeme file ) where are you installing the flutter SDK ( generaly it's installed C:\flutter )try to switch to this directory and create your app file

Answer (score 0):

Do not install Flutter in a directory like C:\Program Files\ that requires elevated privileges. （e.g.for example, C:\src\flutter）

Comment: Thank you, so i should re-install flutter?

Comment: Or add the privilegies until the path of our folder